# Is it possible to use values from a disconnected table to filter selection in a slicer in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a disconnected table that have a column with two Values FisYear and CalYear.

I also have a calendar table with dates and two columns, one FisYear and the second CalYear. The FisYear have values FY2021, FY2122 and FY2223. The CalYear column have values 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023.

The calendar table is connect to the fact table.

I want to have two single value filter visuals, one based on the disconnected table and the other on the calendar table.

The functionality I'm after is when I choose say FisYear, the calendar table would only show the available selections from the FisYear column and similarly for CalYear.

I tried using the SWITCH statement but it's returning and error as it should only return a scalar value and not a list.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what **Field Parameters** are made for:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great solution, field parameters is obviously the best way to go here - much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find a way to add the list of years and also, can the list become filters too?

Comment: if you tried it, you would have noticed that a slicer is automatically added to the page.

Comment: yeah, I tried it and slicer was added to page but couldn't get the list to show - seems I have to break it down by showing values of selected list so it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand. I think you need the following:

1. A new table persisted to your data model that contains the combinations of all `FisYear` years and corresponding dates and all `CalYear` years and corresponding dates.
2. New relationships set up between your selector table, the new "combinations" table and between your new "combinations" table and your existing date table.

The new table would look like this:

```
Combinations = 
VAR _fisYear = ADDCOLUMNS ( 
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Date' , 
        'Date'[Date] , 
        "YearValue" , SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Fiscal Year] ) 
    ), 
    "Selection", "FisYear"
)

VAR _calYear = 
 ADDCOLUMNS ( 
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Date' , 
        'Date'[Date] , 
        "YearValue" , SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Calendar Year] ) 
    ), 
    "Selection", "CalYear"
)

RETURN 
UNION ( _fisYear , _calYear )
```

You can relate this table to your selection table on the `Selection` column. You can relate this table to your existing date table on the `Date` column. When you create the relationship to your date table, specify a many-to-many relationship, and that this new `Combinations` table filters date (and NOT the other way around!).

You should now be able to use the `YearValue` column in a slicer which gives you all the different combinations of fiscal years and calendar years options. When selecting `FisYear` or `CalYear` in a slicer you should only see the corresponding values for `YearValue`.